# Remove \r\n from innerHTML that comes as an API response in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to display HTML text that I am getting as an API response. The API response is like this

```
    <p> Some text </p>
    \r\n
    <p> Some text </p>
    \r\n
    <p> Some text </p>
    \r\n
    <p> Some text </p>
```

and it is getting displayed like this

```
    Some text
    \r\n
    Some text
    \r\n    
    Some text
    \r\n    
    Some text
```

I tried all the ways I could find on the internet to remove \r\n from getting displayed but nothing worked for me. Can anyone please suggest something.

\r\n is not a string it is a part of the html that I am receiving in the API response. That might be the reason

```
string.replace
```

doesnot work here.

Comment: [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey tried that in may ways but didnt work for my scenario.

Comment: OK.  Show us your code.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you receiving a string that contains the four characters `\r\n`, or are you getting a string that contains the **two** characters representing carriage-return and newline? A browser should ignore the latter.

Comment: I added my solution which uses two `replace()` statements to replace all instances of `\r` and `\n` in the string.

Comment: I also added a couple of alternative variations if you didn't want the `p` tags flush together (1 line). I added solutions for keeping the empty line between them (7 lines total, where 3 are blank), or having each line with a separate `p` tag (4 lines total).

Comment: @seanmitchell87 thanks I have tried all these they aren't working for my scenario. So we have requested for the document to be updated accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. We run this as two separate string replacements. Because there are multiple occurrences, we run them as regex expressions with the global flag `/g`. First we replace any instances of `\r` and then we replace any instances of `\n` which will also replace the line breaks between the `p` tags. Let me know if this works for you!

```js
let input =
`<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>`;

let output = input.replace(/\r/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '');

console.log(output);
```

If you only want to remove the instances of `\r\n` together and not remove the line breaks between your `p` tags, this should work as well:

```js
let input =
`<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>`;

let output = input.replace(/\r\n/g, '');

console.log(output);
```

That will leave an empty line between each of your `p` tags. However, if you want the `p` tags on separate lines but don't want an empty space between them, then we just run the same replacement with an extra `\n` after the `\r\n` to replace the `\r` and then the two line breaks following it (`\r\n\n`):

```js
let input =
`<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>
\r\n
<p> Some text </p>`;

let output = input.replace(/\r\n\n/g, '');

console.log(output);
```